# Adding a row to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying tobuild a file browser using JTable for filename, size, etc.
But swing crash when i try add a row in JTable. Can someone tell me, what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/ziaccot/bfd799b9422bbe0fda5f966fc5b5067b)

Comment: *so i posted a link to gist github in my question* - code should be posted in the forum, not on github. We are not interested in your application only an [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Actually, on gist github pasted only "minimal reproducible example".

Comment: Read my comment. Code should be posted in the forum, not on github!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong?
I suspect the `TableModel` has no columns - columns where added to the `ColumnModel` of the table but not to the `TableModel`. At least set its column count to 4.

I also strongly suggest creating the model (`DefaultTableModel`) before creating the table, so it can be used to create the table - no need to add columns to table. Even better use an own model, extending `AbstractTableModel` - gives better control (mostly for non trivial cases).

---

Example (minimal) for own model:

```
class FileInfoModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final String[] columns = {"", "Name", "Size", "Date"};

    private final List<FileInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }        

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columns[col];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        FileInfo info = data.get(row);
        switch (col) {
            case 0: return info.getFileType();
            case 1: return info.getFileName();
            case 2: return info.getFileSize();
            case 3: return info.getLastModified();
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("col: " + col);
        }
    }

    public void addInfo(FileInfo info) {
        if (data.add(info)) {
            var row = data.size() - 1;
            fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }
    }
}
```

no need for an *extended* table, just `new JTable(model)` using above model instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The trouble was with column count.